# How to get href="" in <a> using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a code:

```
<div id='basic-modal'>
<a href='index.php?option=com_atm&view=showdistrict&layout=map&tmpl=component&reset=1' class='basic'>[VIEW]</a>
</div>
```

and script:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('<div></div>').load('link href').modal();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

How to get url from href "index.php?option=com_atm&view=showdistrict&layout=map&tmpl=component&reset=1" of tag  ?

Comment: you can use attr for getting the value in href. `$(this).attr("href")`

Answer (score 1):

try

`alert($(this).attr("href"));`

inside click-function
you can access every *attribute* of an element by jQuerys `attr` function and you can also set or modify an attribute by providing a second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can get attribute values using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). In your example, however, you can use native JavaScript's [`element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute).

Jquery conveniently binds event handlers to the right context (meaning, `this` refers to what you expect it to), i.e. you can simply say `this.getAttribute('href')`. If you really insist on using jQuery, you can say `$(this).attr('href')`, but that's just wasting resources.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('<div></div>').load(this.getAttribute('href')).modal();

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

cleaned up a bit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $('<div />').load($(this).attr('href')).modal();
    });
});
</script>
```